# Vuetify: prevent overflow of chips on combobox

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a combobox with chips using Vuetify, and I want to disable "overflow", as I don't want the combobox to resize, regardless of how many items it holds.

[image: See image that shows how the chips "overflow", they don't keep going right 'out of view']

I tried various forms of `allow-overflow="false"`, `:allow-overflow=false` etc, I can't find a way to get it to work. I've gone through all the [API documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-combobox/) and I can't see anything else that would be relevant.

[Also, is there any way to get the selected items to all appear at the top of the drop-down list?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9axxt.png)

Answer (score 4):

You could use CSS for this:

1. Style the selections (`.v-select__selections`) with [`flex-wrap:nowrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap#values) to prevent the wrapping, and with [`overflow:scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values) to allow scrolling if the selections exceed the width of the container.
2. Style the chip (`.v-chip`) with `overflow:initial` to allow the chip to expand to its full width inside the container (prevents cutting off the chip).

```css
.v-select__selections {
  overflow: scroll;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
.v-chip {
  overflow: initial;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/YzVpLab)

[image: screencast]